# How to write on the left and right side if i have a table that is located in the center?

Tags: html, css

So i have a table that is located on the center of my web page, and now i want to add some text on the left or right side of the table. The text need to be written outside the table. I need to add some more columns to the table and write inside them and play with the CSS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You need to create 3 `div` columns. The first `div` will be the left section the second is the `div` where you will `wrap` your table the third `div` is the right section. Otherwise, post your code so we will know what you have done so far.

Comment: Thank you, that is a briliant idea @threeFatCat

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

A Very Basic [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/04tcy42m/) to get you on the right track!

HTML:

```
<div id="col-1">
    text can go here.
</div>
<div id="col-2">
    <table>

    </table>
</div>
<div id="col-3">
    text can go here...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#col-1,
#col-2,
#col-3 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
#col-2 {
  background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one using Bootstrap 4**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-4 left-section float-left bg-primary text-white">
  <h2>Left Section</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 float-left bg-warning text-white">
   <h2>Basic Table</h2>
   <br>          
   <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>John</td>
         <td>Doe</td>
         <td>john@example.com</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Mary</td>
         <td>Moe</td>
         <td>mary@example.com</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>July</td>
         <td>Dooley</td>
         <td>july@example.com</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 right-section float-right bg-danger text-white">
  <h2>Right Section</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 </div>
</div>
```